# Animation like paypal pay button

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, paypal

[image]

I want to implement a UI like PayPal iOS application's pay button. Can anyone suggest an example or link which has such an animation? See attachment.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you forgot to add the attachment. Please provide an example of how it should look like and the code you tried to make it work.

Comment: I added screen shot exactly now...

Comment: i Guess with POP you can do that... using default library animation effects. you just need to calculate x and Y for your path in this case the slider.

Comment: you can take a look at this. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements_sliders.htm and customize yours. :D

Comment: this would help also.. http://www.raywenderlich.com/36288/how-to-make-a-custom-control